# Thread-safe way to render multiple Winforms local reports (without ReportViewer) simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, rdlc

I have a need to generate several `.rdlc` reports as PDF files in a Winforms app.  There is no need to display the reports.  The app is using the `LocalReport` object to render the reports to PDFs.

This takes a while to do, and I was wondering whether it would be possible to generate each of my reports in a separate thread.  The app has a `GenerateReport` method that takes a report name as a parameter and creates a new, local `LocalReport` object, so it lends itself to wrapping in a `System.Threading.Task`.

However, this seems not to be thread-safe:  it looks as if something deep in the rendering code uses a temp file and all instances of `LocalReport` use that same temp file name.  I get I/O errors because one instance has deleted the temp file and another is still trying to use it.

Is there a thread-safe way to render multiple PDFs from separate .rdlc files, simultaneously?

EDITED TO ADD:  Error message and Stack trace:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\2ngs2k1g.out' because it is being used by another process.

```
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int errorCode, string maybeFullPath) + 0x562 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.File.InternalDelete(string path, bool checkHost) + 0xd6 bytes    
System.dll!System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.Delete(string fileName) + 0x16 bytes  
System.dll!System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.Delete() + 0x54 bytes 
System.dll!System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.SafeDelete() + 0x33 bytes 
System.dll!System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromDomBatch(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit[] ea) + 0xa6 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExprHostCompiler.InternalCompile(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Report report, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool refusePermissions) + 0x50c bytes  
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExprHostCompiler.Compile.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x51 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run.AnonymousMethod__0(object state) + 0x83 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(System.Security.SecurityContext securityContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x96 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ContextBody callback) + 0xd4 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExprHostCompiler.Compile(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Report report, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool refusePermissions) + 0xfb bytes   
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.Phase3(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext reportContext, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection parameters, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, out System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int> groupingExprCountAtScope) + 0x826 bytes  
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext reportContext, byte[] definition, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.IChunkFactory createChunkCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ResolveTemporaryDataSource resolveTemporaryDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfoCollection originalDataSources, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.PublishingErrorContext errorContext, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.IDataProtection dataProtection, out string description, out string language, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out System.Collections.ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks) + 0x20c bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext reportContext, byte[] reportDefinition, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.IChunkFactory createChunkCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ResolveTemporaryDataSource resolveTemporaryDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfoCollection originalDataSources, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.PublishingErrorContext errorContext, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.IDataProtection dataProtection, out string reportDescription, out string reportLanguage, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out System.Collections.ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks) + 0x184 bytes   
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext reportContext, byte[] reportDefinition, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.IChunkFactory createChunkFactory, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ResolveTemporaryDataSource resolveTemporaryDataSourceCallback, Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataSourceInfoCollection originalDataSources, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingFlags processingFlags, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.IDataProtection dataProtection) + 0x1f0 bytes  
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext reportContext, byte[] reportDefinition, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.IChunkFactory createChunkFactory, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, System.AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingFlags processingFlags, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.IDataProtection dataProtection) + 0xa2 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ICatalogItemContext context, byte[] reportDefinition, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ControlSnapshot snapshot) + 0x1b3 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.PreviewStore.StoredReport.EnsureCompiled(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContextBase itemContext) + 0xa1 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.PreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContextBase context, bool rebuild, out byte[] reportDefinition, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ControlSnapshot snapshot) + 0x323 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.PreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContextBase context, bool rebuild, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ControlSnapshot snapshot) + 0x5a bytes   
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, bool rebuild, out Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ControlSnapshot snapshot) + 0x66 bytes   
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, bool rebuild) + 0x54 bytes 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession() + 0xd6 bytes  
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll!Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> parameters) + 0xc5 bytes    
XXXXX.exe!XXXX.WinClient.SQLRS.Print(int YyyyID, string ReportName, bool copy, bool CreatePDF) Line 151 + 0x31 bytes
```

Comment: According to Microsoft, instance members of LocalReport are not guaranteed to be thread safe. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport(v=vs.90).aspx )

Comment: @Alex Isn't that info the OP is already aware of?

Comment: @rene That could be, I was just making sure that she's aware of the fact that you (according to Microsoft) cannot use LocalReport in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: Can you share the exact StackTrace?

Comment: You could use threads, but ensure, what only one at time is accessing `LocalReport` (use `lock`, make a wrapper to hide exclusive access).

Comment: @rene Stack trace added.

Comment: @Sinatr  Even if I have multiple instances of `LocalReport`?  If I have to run the reports serially (one at a time) it defeats the purpose of using multiple threads.

Comment: Obivously, but you will ensure it's safe and still can use Tasks (to create sort of queue for multiple reports). Perhaps you could also do something else in there, to example, generating actual reports.

Comment: Are you generating the same report with different parameters? Or they all different reports? Can you try if starting Generate in a different AppDomains helps? A nasty solution would be to start a complete different process, have the pdf stored in a temp folder and read it back once the external app has finished...

Comment: @rene They're all different reports.

Comment: @rene I dug into the code with Reflector and found that at a certain point while compiling the report, it created a temporary AppDomain with the hard-coded name `report_compilation_temp_appdomain`.  I don't know enough about AppDomains to know if that's the root cause of what I saw, but it does seem to establish that there's no true thread safe way to do what I want.

Comment: Yeah, I basically did the same :-) didn't find that one though. I'm afraid your only option is then to spin several processes. :-(

Comment: @rene  If you want to write what we found up as an answer, I'll give you the credit; otherwise, I'll do it myself in a few days.  Thanks!

Comment: @AnnL. I'll give it a try but that won't happen until tomorrow...tnx :-)

Comment: @AnnL. I have been trying to recreate this exception but somehow that doesn't happen. Is there anything special in those reports? I tried adding assemblies and stuff and it won't break.

Comment: @rene They exist as .rdlc files in the file system (not resources), they're all different .rdlc files, and they use the `LocalReport.SetParameters` method, which, together with being an external file, forces a recompile of the report. It's the simultaneous compiles that's doing it, I think.

Comment: Hmmm, that is what I have...let me tweak it a little bit more...

Comment: @rene I just thought of something:  I think these are the .NET 4.0 versions.

Comment: @AnnL. OK, that is what I'm using as well. How does that matter?

Comment: @rene I don't know that it does, I just thought it might be a difference.

Comment: It's just a hunch, but the *WebForms* version of ReportViewer might work better for this than the *WinForms* version: After all, web applications are multi-threaded by nature...

Comment: @Heinzi That's interesting! But, could I even instantiate it in a WinForms app, I wonder? This was an app that ran on field representatives' laptops, and they didn't necessarily have internet access in the places where they worked. (I left that client 5 years ago, so I can't test the hypothesis anymore!)

Comment: Good question. I never tried it and, unfortunately, the differences between the WinForms and the WebForms versions are not really well documented.